# How to move to different WiFi network without restarting all my programs?

Tags: wireless-networking

When I go from my home WiFi to a public WiFi near a store I work at, my computer has no problem switching to the new network, but the programs I'm running (i.e.Facebook) need to be restarted so they can see the new network. I'd like to put my laptop to sleep when I leave home and wake it up in the new WiFi network without having to restart all my programs. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Rather than having to restart programs and reload pages, you should give your computer a minute to connect to the network and establish an IP address.  When you relocate and wake your computer, connecting to the WiFi at the new location is not an instant process.

Certain pages that rely on heavy Javascript such as Facebook might require you to hit reload once you've changed locations, but you shouldn't have to logout altogether or actually close the tab or window.  Others such as Gmail tend to recover just fine on their own given enough time.